# What expression should I use to get desired results?

Tags: regex

For strings like `Cisco 3750 i7706-cm021 10.123.12.34 -> 10.123.34.12` I would like to get result `Cisco 3750 i7706-cm021 10.123.12.34 ->` using expression `^.*(?![\d\.]{12}$)`. But instead a whole string is matched. What is the correct expression would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a regex like

```
^.*?(?=\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/is6Zam/2) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E.*%3F(%3F%3D%5Cb(%3F%3A%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.)%7B3%7D%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%24)):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}$)` - a positive lookahead that requires (immediately to the right of the current location):

  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}` - three repetitions of 1 to 3 digits and a dot
  - `\d{1,3}` - one to three digits
  - `$` - end of string.

To get more precise IP regex, see [*How to Find or Validate an IP Address*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html):

```
^.*?(?=\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$)
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/is6Zam/3)

Comment: @Safety1st [Here is the IP regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html). Add `$` at the end.